# Java int array to HashMap<Integer, Boolean> with IntStream

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to take square of each array element and insert a entry to hashmap with this value as a key and true as a value. I have tried to do it like that but I can not fix it.

```
int [] array = {3, 1, 4, 6, 5};

    HashMap<Integer, Boolean> map = IntStream.of(array)
            .map(x -> x*x)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> Integer.valueOf(p), Boolean.valueOf(true)));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `box` the `IntStream` and proceed with a `Stream<Integer>` :

```
Map<Integer, Boolean> map = IntStream.of(array)
        .map(x -> x*x)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p, p -> Boolean.valueOf(true)));
```

Note that `Collectors.toMap` returns a `Map`, not a `HashMap`.

Comment: @ugurdonmez Sorry about that. Fixed now.

Comment: Since there is a mapping step anyway, an extra `boxed()` step is unnecessary. Further, `Boolean.valueOf(true)` is obsolete: `Arrays.stream(array).mapToObj(x -> x*x) .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p, p -> true))`

Answer (score 0):

`you can use a simple loop

int [] array = {3, 1, 4, 6, 5};

```
HashMap<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

for(int i : array) {
   map.put(i*i, true);
}
```